# Is Telnet Port Open For The Range IP?

Tags: port, telnet, nmap

I want to port scanning on telnet port in a range ip . 
for ex: i want to know is the 23 port open on 127.0.0.1/255 ?
what am i going to do ? is there a option for Nmap to do this ? 
Thanks .

Comment: Why not just do `telnet 127.0.0.1 23`?

Comment: no , i want test is the telnet port open for this range 127.0.0.1/255 ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes:

nmap -p 23 127.0.0.0/24

Will scan port 23 on 127.0.0.0-127.0.0.255.  The /24 is CIDR notation, more info on that here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation

Comment: If the hosts are blocking ping, the default nmap behavior is to assume they are down.  Add the `-P0` flag to your nmap invocation to make nmap assume the hosts are up.

Comment: @Phil: `-P0` is deprecated : `This option flag used to be P0, but was renamed to PN avoid confusion with protocol ping´s PO` (man nmap)

Answer (score 1):

If you're scanning the range of 127.0.0.1/24 - you're only looking on your localhost (and unless you're doing something sorta funky, the only hit you should get is on 127.0.0.1).

Are you *sure* that's the range you want to scan?

It would be faster to run `netstat -an > openports.txt` from a command prompt, then see if 23 is listening.

Answer (score 0):

sorry i cant send a comment but i test the option : nmap -p 23 127.0.0.0/24 and the result is : its looklike dont work well ...

nmap -p 23 188.34.95.0/24

Starting Nmap 4.11 ( http://www.insecure.org/nmap/ ) at 2011-08-29 07:10 PDT
Nmap finished: 256 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 20.399 seconds

Comment: in the very same subnet, I found a lot of hosts up : `Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (17 hosts up) scanned in 12.06 seconds`

Comment: but why i get Nmap finished: 256 IP addresses (0 hosts up) ? is this for nmap version ?

Comment: maybe on 4.11 this scan needs to be run as root?

Comment: iam in ssh and my access is root , and in windows i test it and get the same result (in windows nmap version is 5.51) ; iam getting confused !!! what is your nmap version ?

Comment: I wonder if there's a firewall blocking outgoing telnet between you and your target network?  You can try "traceroute -T -p 23 188.34.95.184" or something like that to see if there's a block someplace.  Note that, even though I just tried the same nmap and got 24 hosts reporting with an open telnet, I can't telnet to a sample of those machines.

Comment: i found the problem : we can not check :nmap -p 23 188.34.95.0/24 for our isp , its not work for me because iam belong to a ip from 188.34.95.0/24 ; and i test this command from a remote desktop and its work well ... Thanks